# Zero being dropped from array

Tags: powershell

I have noticed is that if the 'version' ends in a zero, then that zero is being dropped.

So, for example, if the 'version' in the `$statusContent` is `1.9.7.680`, then `$version` is `1.9.7.68`. Is there a way to keep that zero?

```
$version = $statusContent.Content.Substring(145).TrimEnd('" counter="0" /></mibscalar>')
```

Sample string:

```
<mibscalar name="appRunningApp" type="readonly" link= "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/v1/mib/objs/appRunningApp?type=xml"; ><data index="1" value="ma xtime - 1.9.7.680" counter="0" /></mibscalar>
```

Comment: Can you share an example string you're trying to process and what exactly you want to extract?

Comment: Sure, here's an example:

<mibscalar name="appRunningApp" type="readonly" link=
"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/v1/mib/objs/appRunningApp?type=xml" ><data index="1" value="ma
xtime - 1.9.7.680" counter="0" /></mibscalar>

All I want to extract is the 1.9.7.680 portion.

Comment: PLease edit your question to add this information

Comment: So is this coming from a well formed XML file?

Comment: Yes, the only thing I compensate for is the length of the IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TrimEnd()` is not the function you're looking for - it turns the string argument into a character array and eats away every occurrence of *any* of those characters from the end of the string until it can't find anymore.

Use `Remove()` instead to cut off the trailing part:

```
$string = $statusContent.Content.Substring(145)
$tail = '" counter="0" /></mibscalar>'

if($string.EndsWith($tail)){
    # [string]::Remove() takes a start index as it's first argument
    # Let's calculate the index at which we'll start removing characters
    $string = $string.Remove($string.Length - $tail.Length)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regular expression?

```
> $txt
<mibscalar name="appRunningApp" type="readonly" link= "127.0.0.2/v1/mib/objs/appRunningApp?type=xml"; ><data index="1" value="ma xtime - 1.9.7.680" counter="0" /></mibscalar>

> if ($txt -match '\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+(?=\")') { $version = $matches[0] }

> $version
1.9.7.680
```

**EDIT**:

Now that I'm aware `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` bit was an IP address I had to change regular expression in above code to avoid matching it. IP addresses are too similar in their pattern to versions to tell them apart looking just at them.

I've added a lookahead `(?=\")` that matches only if `"` follows the pattern. It will work as long as quotes closes immediately after version number. You could as another option have a negative lookahead `(?!\/)` to make sure `/` is *not* following a pattern to make sure it's not and `<IP>/<path>` kind of string.

Comment: Ah, so `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` would be an IP address?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.